# Spotlight built-in calculator does not work

Tags: macos, spotlight

After the latest OS X update to 10.10.2, Spotlight built-in calculator stopped working. I tried to disable/enable it in settings and reboot, but nothing helped.

Am I the only one who is fighting this? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this command in terminal? 
`defaults write com.apple.spotlight CalculationEnabled YES` 
Source: [Spotlight doesn't solve math equations any more](http://superuser.com/questions/8516/spotlight-doesnt-solve-math-operations-any-more)

Comment: @Tyler, this does not change anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you do and I notice that the problem was that I have conversion disabled on System Preferentes

So I went to System Preferences > Spotlight, enabled it and it solved my problem.

Comment: oh, apple, apple. this solves my problem. why then there is Calculator checkbox? xD

Comment: mine already had 'Conversion' selected. but I deselected and reselected it, and then it started working again. thanks

Comment: This also works for High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

I have done the way suggested by @portella 5 years ago, but it does not solve my problem. I am using macOS Catalina (ver 10.15.14), and so it is newer than that where the suggestion worked. I guess that the issue in Catalina comes from a different cause.

After trial and error, which is just checking-in and checking-out boxes in preferences of Spotlight, I found that at least for my case, enabling "Applications" works, somehow. I guess that because in this version, calculator is recognized as one of applications, using calculator in spotlight requires permission of using applications.

In short, for macOS Catalina, enabling System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Applications may solve the issue.

Comment: Where does one do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Same. Enabling Applications in System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Applications solved the issue!

Comment: Sorry! I neglected the clarity of the explanation. I have added some description.
Also I used phrase of @IlyaKarnaukhov. Since this and his post are essentially same, should both be merged?

Comment: In 10.15.4 you also have to explicitly allow Calculator and Conversions

Comment: wow, thanks, solved by checking "Applications", after many months of not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Applications in System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Applications solved the issue for me.